# changing mapping field for @XmlValue in @JsonProperty

Tags: java, json, xml, jackson, swagger

I have an element "**SubElement2**" that has value and attribute.

**Working :**

My Annotation are

```
    @XmlValue    
    @JsonProperty(value="content")
    private String value;
```

Request in XML : `<SubElement2  parameterName = "tested">ELEMENT_2_TAG_VAL</SubElement2>`

TO JSON :

```
{
  "SubElement2" : {
    "content" : "ELEMENT_2_TAG_VAL",
    "parameterName" : "tested"
  }
}
```

Here I want to change the property name **content** to **myOwnContent**

**Not Working:**

Modified annotations :

```
    @XmlValue    
    @JsonProperty(value="myOwnContent")  // Modified
    private String value;
```

Request in XML : `<SubElement2  parameterName = "tested">ELEMENT_2_TAG_VAL</SubElement2>`

> **For the above annotation change, I'm facing below exception:**

```
Exception in thread "main" com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.UnrecognizedPropertyException: Unrecognized field "content" (class SubElement2), not marked as ignorable (2 known properties: "parameterName", "myOwnContent"])
 at [Source: (String)"{"SubElement2":{"parameterName":"tested","content":"ELEMENT_2_TAG_VAL"}}"; line: 1, column: 53] (through reference chain: Element1["SubElement2"]->SubElement2["content"])
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.UnrecognizedPropertyException.from(UnrecognizedPropertyException.java:60)
```

Below is my code :
**ObjectFactory.java**

```
@XmlRegistry
public class ObjectFactory {

    public SubElement2 createSubElement2() {
        return new SubElement2();
    }
}
```

**MainProgram.java**

```
public class MainProgram {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws ClassNotFoundException, IOException {
        String request = "<SubElement2  parameterName = \"tested\">ELEMENT_2_TAG_VAL</SubElement2>";
        System.out.println("Request in XML : "+request);
        JSONObject jObject = XML.toJSONObject(request);

        ObjectMapper mapper = createCombinedObjectMapper();
        Object json = mapper.readValue(jObject.toString(), Class.forName("Element1"));
        String output = mapper.writerWithDefaultPrettyPrinter().writeValueAsString(json);
        System.out.println(output);
    }

    private static ObjectMapper createCombinedObjectMapper() {
        return new ObjectMapper().configure(SerializationFeature.WRAP_ROOT_VALUE, false)
                .configure(DeserializationFeature.UNWRAP_ROOT_VALUE, false)
                .configure(DeserializationFeature.ACCEPT_SINGLE_VALUE_AS_ARRAY, true)
                .setAnnotationIntrospector(createJaxbJacksonAnnotationIntrospector());
    }

    private static AnnotationIntrospector createJaxbJacksonAnnotationIntrospector() {
        final AnnotationIntrospector jaxbIntrospector = new JaxbAnnotationIntrospector(TypeFactory.defaultInstance());
        final AnnotationIntrospector jacksonIntrospector = new JacksonAnnotationIntrospector();
        return AnnotationIntrospector.pair(jacksonIntrospector, jaxbIntrospector);
    }

}
```

**SubElement2.java**

```
@XmlRootElement(name = "SubElement2")
public class SubElement2 {
    @XmlValue    
    @JsonProperty(value="myOwnContent")
    private String value;
    @JsonProperty(value="parameterName",required=true)
    @XmlAttribute(required = true)
    protected String parameterName;
    public String getValue() {
        return value;
    }
    public void setValue(String value) {
        this.value = value;
    }
    public String getParameterName() {
        return parameterName;
    }
    public void setParameterName(String parameterName) {
        this.parameterName = parameterName;
    }
}
```

**Element1.java**

```
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
@XmlType(name = "element1", propOrder = {
    "element1"
})
@XmlRootElement(name = "Element1")
public class Element1 {

    @XmlElement(name="SubElement2")
    protected SubElement2 subElement2;

    public SubElement2 getSubElement2() {
        return subElement2;
    }

    public void setSubElement2(SubElement2 subElement2) {
        this.subElement2 = subElement2;
    }
}
```

I'm using Jackson version : 2.9.7

> Help me to solve this exception ,thanks in advance
>
> What I want to do :

I want to have jsonproperty as `myOwnContent` because `content` is already used by another attribute in `XML` in my existing implementation. (Existing implementation doesn't have JSON suuport , we are adding JSON support)

Comment: Why do you want to deserialise result `JSON` to `Element1`? You deserialise `XML` payload to `SubElement2` class and after that probably serialise `SubElement2` instance to `JSON` (`JSONObject` ?!?). Later you want to deserialise it to `Element1` but `Element1` does not match to `SubElement2`. Why you do not deserialise it to `SubElement2`?

Comment: Sorry,I don't understand what you are asking , but one thing I want to have jsonproperty as `myOwnContent` because `content` is already used by another attribute in `XML`

Comment: I checked flow in `main` method and it looks like you convert `XML` to `JSON` and after that try to deserialise `JSON` to `Element1` but given `XML` fits to `SubElement2`. Could you please create runnable example which shows the error? Right now I do not know what is going on behind `XML.toJSONObject(request)`. Also, why do you load class by `Class.forName("Element1")`?